# Re-entering the UK after our honeymoon

Tags: air-travel, uk, passports, weddings

I am an Australian citizen with an Australian passport.

I currently hold a UK marriage visitor visa and my fiancee and I are getting married in September. After our marriage we are planning to go overseas for our honeymoon and then re-enter the UK in  a week.

My fiancee is a British passport holder, so she has  no issues. However, I heard that my fiancee visa will cease after we get married. So can I go back to the UK as a visitor after our honeymoon? Australian passport holders don't need a visa to visit the UK.

Comment: How long do you plan to be in the UK after the honeymoon?  Where do you plan to reside, long-term?

Comment: Which is it that you hold? A fiance visa or a marriage visitor visa? They are very different.

Comment: "Fiancee visa" usually refers to a visa that allows one to go to the UK for the purpose of marrying someone and then remaining indefinitely.  The marriage visitor visa is a different visa that does not allow its bearer to remain in the UK for longer than six months.  Which visa do you have?  How long do you want to stay in the UK after your honeymoon?  (Also, for an unrelated matter of curiosity, does your fiancee reside in the UK?  Thanks.)